Issue with LIFF Redirect from Page A to Page B
I'd like to inquire about an questions regarding LIFF.
On Page A(Entry point), which lacks liff.init, there's a button that will navigate to Page B (a different URL).
Page B, does have liff.init initialized.
When I click the button on Page A to navigate to Page B, it keeps redirecting back to Page A.
Are there any relevant documents or explanations for this behavior? Thank you!

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
